# Flow: Generate object type "Y" from object type "X" where "Y" has all the same keys as "X", but all the types are string

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Lets say we have a type such as:

```
type X = {|
  a: number,
  b: number,
|}
```

I'd like to create a type `Y` that has the type

```
type Y = {|
  a: string,
  b: string,
|}
```

I figured it might be possible with `$ObjMap` despite the fact that it's currently considered unstable, but

```
type X = {|
  a: number,
  b: number
|}
type Y = $ObjMap<X, any => string>
const y: Y = {
  a: 1,
  b: 1,
  c: 1
}
```

yields no flow errors. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this comment in issue 2674](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2674#issuecomment-255603036), `$ObjMap` currently allows invalid writes and literal assignments. I believe this situation would fall under the latter issue.

You could potentially try a stop-gap solution such as this:

```
type X = {|
  a: number,
  b: number
|}
type Y = { [$Keys<X>]: string };
const y: Y = {
  a: 1,
  b: 1,
  c: 1
}
```

That will catch the extra key `c`, as well as the invalid `number` values, but it will not warn you about missing keys.

Comment: Never heard of `$ObjMapi` O_o what's the difference?

Comment: Also both `test` and `test2` give me errors flow errors, but I'd expect that `test` would give me no errors.

Comment: The difference between "map" and "mapi" is the same as OCaml's `Map.map` and `Map.mapi` -- i.e., the former has a single parameter, a value type, while the latter has two parameters, the key and the value type. Unfortunately my original example had problems of its own, and did not solve the problem. I've updated my answer to be what I believe to be the current state of affairs.